# Handle UserControl children events

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have an `UserControl` that contains a `Button`:

```
<UserControl>
   <Button>
</UserControl>
```

I want to handle the [`Button` events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button_events) (like Click, Loaded, ...), for example to use:

```
MyUCtrl.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MyUCtrl_Click);
```

that is equivalent to:

```
MyButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MyUCtrl_Click);
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redeclare the event on the UserControl, subscribe to the Button's event internally and raise the event of the UserControl in the handler.

Comment: @Nick: Possibly, but one can never say for sure.